# Any penalty for playing dirty in baseball?

Tags: rules, baseball

Manny Machado of the Dodgers has been noticed as making a number of dirty plays, stepping on infielders' feet or trying to kick them as he slides. For example, in the NLCS he was on first when the batter hit into a double play and he broke it up by deliberately sliding into the shortstop and even tried using his hand to grab the fielder's leg to take him down.

[image]

Is there any kind of interference rule or unsportsmanlike conduct rule that can be used in cases like this? What is the penalty?

Comment: The first rule of NFL Fight Club is that we do not talk about NFL Fight Club!

Answer (score 1):

[MLB slide rule](http://m.mlb.com/glossary/rules/slide-rule)

> When sliding into a base in an attempt to break up a double play, a
>   runner has to make a "bona fide slide." Such is defined as the runner
>   making contact with the ground before reaching the base, being able to
>   reach the base with a hand or foot, being able to remain on the base
>   at the completion of the slide (except at home plate) and not changing
>   his path for the purpose of initiating contact with a fielder. The
>   slide rule prohibits runners from using a "roll block" or attempting
>   to initiate contact with the fielder by elevating and kicking his leg
>   above the fielder's knee, throwing his arm or his upper body or
>   grabbing the fielder. When a violation of the slide rule occurs, the
>   offending runner and the batter-runner will be called out.

Looks to me like he threw his arm but not really conclusive.

There is also a rule on unsportsmanlike conduct.